# How to set time schedule programatically in timer jobs using sharepoint 2013(Farm solution)

Tags: custom-timer-job, farm-solution

I am trying to create one timer job in SharePoint 2013 
Now I want to set 1 minute in timer job using event receiver after deploy timer job in farm solution.

Now timer jobs run perfectly but its run as per default time 15 minutes By Sharepoint.

I want to set time In timer job as per event receiver set.

I tried the following:

```
  private bool CreateJob(SPWebApplication site)
    {
        bool jobCreated = false;
        try
        {
            TimerJobDemo job = new TimerJobDemo(JobName, site);
            SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
            schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
            schedule.EndSecond = 59;
            schedule.Interval = 1;
            job.Schedule = schedule;

            job.Update();
            job.RunNow();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return jobCreated;
        }
        return jobCreated;
    }
```